# Calculating tangency co-ordinates and angles

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

I have a challenge - how to work out the co-ordinates (circled in red) and then the  2 angles of the triangle from vertical (also circled in red).

Is it possible to put this into an equation so that the highlighted dimensions are expressed in terms of the input variables.

I have not been able to find anything else helpful online so I thought I would let the experts take a look.

[image]

Comment: What exactly are the “input variables?”

Comment: all the other dimensions that are not circled in red.